# DOMDocument warning parse html text entity 'nbsp' not defined

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I try parse an utf-8 html text but I get this error

> Warning: DOMDocumentFragment::appendXML(): Entity: line 1: parser
>   error : Entity 'nbsp' not defined

I define:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml(mb_convert_encoding($richText, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"));
```

this is full code:

```
function putBetweenText($richText,$webinfo,$url,$keywords,$type = null,$display,$inline)
{

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml(mb_convert_encoding($richText, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8"));

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach($xpath->query('//text()[not(ancestor::a)]') as $node)
{
    $replaced = str_ireplace('.', '.'.randomText($webinfo,$url,$richText,null,$display,$inline), $node->wholeText);
    $newNode  = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
    $newNode->appendXML($replaced);
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild($newNode, $node);
}
return mb_substr($dom->saveXML($xpath->query('//body')->item(0)), 6, -7, "UTF-8");

}
```

Answer (score -6):

Change:

```
putBetweenText($richText,$webinfo,$url,$keywords,$type = null,$display,$inline)
```

to:

```
 putBetweenText($richText, $webinfo, $url, $keywords, $type , $display, $inline)
```

You can call the function similar to:

```
putBetweenText('rich text value', $webinfo_setFromHere, 'http://www.google.com', $keywords_array, 'integer' , 'TRUE', $makeIt_inline)
```

nbsp is not inside an echo statement wherever it is.

You can't put variable assignments into functions, you can only pass them in, or say they're from outside the function($var1, $var2, $var3) by saying global.

$type = null is illegal.
You should assign variables being received, but not passed into the function like: global $a, $b;

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It explains what the problem of something being undefined is, but he posted the wrong code.

Comment: You should write it as comment not as answer

Comment: I decided to edit the obvious issues

Comment: finally I replace all &nbsp; to space ... the problem solved. but I know it is not correct way.

Comment: Where is the nbsp in the code you wrote?  I only see a space in it.

Comment: Did the answer solve the question thoroughly enough?

Comment: This is a great and does all the things +1.

Comment: Now @aliaan needs to mark the question as "solved", and I'll be happy.

Comment: this doesn't solve the issue. `nbsp` is not an entity in XML. See the linked post in the comments above.

Comment: even if it's a dupe, and someone answers it, that doesn't mean it should be marked downward.  It should be purely on the quality of the answer

Comment: and the answer quality isn't there. this doesn't correct the problem.